# aggregate data frame to typical year/week

Tags: r, aggregate, posixct

so i have a large data frame with a date time column of class POSIXct and a another column with price data of class numeric.  the date time column has values of the form "1998-12-07 02:00:00 AEST" that are half hour observations across 20 years.  a sample data set can be generated with the following code (vary the 100 to whatever number of observations are necessary):

```
data.frame(date.time = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("1998-12-07 02:00:00 AEST"), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1), by = "30 min")[1:100], price = rnorm(100))
```

i want to look at a typical year and typical week.  so for the typical year i have the following code:

```
mean.year <- aggregate(df$price, by = list(format(df$date.time, "%m-%d %H:%M")), mean)
```

it seems to give me what i want:

```
      Group.1        x
1 01-01 00:00 31.86200
2 01-01 00:30 34.20526
3 01-01 01:00 28.40105
4 01-01 01:30 26.01684
5 01-01 02:00 23.68895
6 01-01 02:30 23.70632
```

however the column "Group.1" is of class character and i would like it to be of class POSIXct.  how can i do this?

for the typical week i have the following code

```
mean.week <- aggregate(df$price, by = list(format(df$date.time, "%wday %H:%M")), mean)
```

the output is as follows

```
     Group.1        x
1 0day 00:00 33.05613
2 0day 00:30 30.92815
3 0day 01:00 29.26245
4 0day 01:30 29.47959
5 0day 02:00 29.18380
6 0day 02:30 25.99400
```

again, column "Group.1" is of class character and i would like POSIXct.  also, i would like to have the day of the week as "Monday", "Tuesday", etc.  instead of 0day.  how would i do this?

Comment: You might already know that you should [provide example data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) next to your code?

Comment: @jay.sf   you are right.  the question has been edited now.

Comment: I do not think `Group.1` can be POSIXct, since it does not contain a date-part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the datetime to a character string that can validly be converted back to POSIXct and then do so:

```
mean.year <- aggregate(df["price"], 
  by = list(time = as.POSIXct(format(df$date.time, "2000-%m-%d %H:%M"))), mean)
head(mean.year)
##                  time       price
## 1 2000-12-07 02:00:00 -0.56047565
## 2 2000-12-07 02:30:00 -0.23017749
## 3 2000-12-07 03:00:00  1.55870831
## 4 2000-12-07 03:30:00  0.07050839
## 5 2000-12-07 04:00:00  0.12928774
## 6 2000-12-07 04:30:00  1.71506499
```

To get the day of the week use `%a` or `%A` -- see `?strptime` for the list of percent codes.

```
mean.week <- aggregate(df["price"], 
  by = list(time = format(df$date.time, "%a %H:%M")), mean)
head(mean.week)
##        time       price
## 1 Mon 02:00 -0.56047565
## 2 Mon 02:30 -0.23017749
## 3 Mon 03:00  1.55870831
## 4 Mon 03:30  0.07050839
## 5 Mon 04:00  0.12928774
## 6 Mon 04:30  1.71506499
```

### Note

The input `df` in reproducible form -- note that `set.seed` is needed to make it reproducible:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date.time = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("1998-12-07 02:00:00 AEST"),
  as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1), by = "30 min")[1:100], price = rnorm(100))
```